# ENOTEMPTY error when creating project with skeleton on Brunch

Tags: javascript, git, build, command-prompt, brunch

I'm on windows...when I create a project with `brunch new projectname` it works, but when I specify a skeleton I get this error:

```
c:\xampp-portable\htdocs>brunch new marionette --skeleton https://github.com/SimbCo/brunch-with-marionette.git
09 Apr 12:14:52 - log: Created skeleton directory layout
09 Apr 12:14:52 - error: { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'c:\xampp-portable\htdocs\marionette\.git\objects\00']
errno: 53,
code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
path: 'c:\\xampp-portable\\htdocs\\marionette\\.git\\objects\\00' }
```

any ideas?

Comment: I didn't manage to figure it out, but what I've noticed is:

* this is a windows-related issue (everything is fine on my mac, breaks on my win8 laptop)
* *you can still use git clone to set up a new project**

I'll post an issue on their repo now.

Answer (score 0):

To quote Paul Miller ([link](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/544#issuecomment-17293950)):

> simply clone git repo and remove `.git` directory, then execute `npm install`. that’s what `brunch new` does

That made it for me :)